# BASEmesh plugin error while interpolation between quality and elevation mesh

Tags: interpolation, plugins

I am creating a 2D hydronumeric model of a watershed. The quality meshing and elevation meshing are fine, but I am getting the following error during interpolation. Does anyone know what should I do?

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shuvom/.qgis2/python/plugins\BASEmesh\interpolation\interpolation_dialog.py", line 171, in accept
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Interpolation", "Nr points with special treatment: %d." % result, QgsMessageBar.INFO, 3)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str


Python version: 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.28 Las Palmas, aa30730ac6 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/Shuvom/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Shuvom/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\bin
C:\Users\Shuvom\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Shuvom/.qgis2//python
C:/Users/Shuvom/Desktop/Watershed
```